# Need to understand meaning of two lambda on single line in python

Tags: python

I have below function in my code, I do not understand the meaning of it. Can anyone please guide me.

```
x = lambda a: lambda a: a + 10
print(x)
print(x(3))
```

Output:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x2adc7e51d1e0>
<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x2adc7e654ea0>
```

Comment: Well the function `x` returns a function but the first `a` is pointless. Call it with `x("doesn't matter")(15)` and you get 25.

Comment: *I do not understand the meaning of it. Can anyone please guide me.* - can you be more specific? Do you know what `lambda`s are?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's similar to this code function:

```
def myFunc(x):
   return lambda b: b + 10

x = lambda a: myFunc(a)
```

note that the parameter on myFunc is not used, completely useless.

Comment: I was a bit messy in the first version, I edited,  but you get the idea :)